# Python LIME not working with missing data

Tags: python, xgboost

I have a dataset where imputing missing values doesn't make sense, as I have variables such as number of days since an action (which would be missing if the action hasnt taken place). One dirty fix would be to impute for each variable useing different logic in each place, but I don't want to go down that road.

The xgboost handles this well, but LIME doesn't seem to support missing values, as I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Domain error in arguments.
```

When running the following code:

```
expXGB = explainer.explain_instance(X_test
[i], model.predict_proba, num_features=7)
expXGB.show_in_notebook(show_table=True)
```

Are there any work arounds for getting LIME plots with missing values?

Comment: Hi, where you able to figure something out for this?